# Change vector path color for Android textview

Tags: android

I need to change 2 paths color for a SVG... I use this SGV on TextView background.
How to change that colors? (on textview SGV background).
I have no idea about it.

SGV:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="26"
    android:viewportWidth="137" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:name="body" android:fillColor="#719405" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M0,0l129,0l8,8l0,18l-137,0z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:name="fold" android:fillAlpha="0.5" android:fillColor="#121726"
        android:fillType="evenOdd" android:pathData="M129,0l8,8l-8,0z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

I tried this lib: https://github.com/devsideal/VectorChildFinder

But it not working to change a image that I will use on TextView background.

```
val image = ImageView(context)

val vector = VectorChildFinder(context, R.drawable.tag, image)
val path1 = vector.findPathByName("body")
val path2 = vector.findPathByName("fold")
path1.setFillColor(Color.RED)
path1.fillAlpha = 0.2f

image.invalidate()
firstTag.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.tag)
```

Comment: Can't we have two separate SVGs with the two different colors that you need and apply anyone as background when required and change when needed?

Comment: I need to use only 1 svg...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it...
Just get the ImageView drawable and set it on the TextView background

```
firstTag.background = image.drawable
```